# CCSprite doesn't run actions when it is child of custom class which parent is CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm renaming old post.
After suggestions provided here, I made several tests and found that CCSprite doesn't run actions when it is child of an object which is instance of a custom class which parent is CCSprite

whats wrong?

Comment: is the sprite actually displayed in the second case?

Comment: Yes it is displayed but doesn't performs action

Comment: what kind of node is `tempCell`?

Comment: tempCell is my custom class subclass of CCSprite. I'm making conversion and then I use boardCell, but result is same, so I didn't mentioned it here NSAssert([tempCell isKindOfClass:[CCBoardCellSprite class]], @"Assertion failure, Wrong Object");
        CCBoardCellSprite *boardCell = (CCBoardCellSprite *)tempCell;

Comment: what if you replace your `tempCell` by a standard node such as `CCLayer`? Do you still have the issue?

Comment: getChildByTag has been superceded by the more flexible getChildByName

Comment: fiddler, I tried as you suggested, i.e I replaced my custom with CCSprite and everything was ok. Now Question is why action works when node which should perform action is child of CCSprite, and doesn't works when it is child of custom class derived from CCSprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In my custom class I was overriding - (void)onEnter function without calling [super onEnter];

now my onEnter function looks like:

- (void)onEnter {
  // call super implementation
  [super onEnter];

  self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
  }

It fixed animation problem